# Ligar tela android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Seguinte, tenho um `BroadCast` e quero que quando ele executar a tela do celular seja ligada! 
Provavelmente o celular vai estar em sleep, dai quero que ele ligue a tela do aparelho! 
Creio que seja simples, mas não estou achando uma solução!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é o `BroadcastReceiver` chamar uma `Activity` que ao ser exibida fará a tela ser ligada e, se necessário, destravada (*unlocked*). Isso é feito da seguinte maneira:

```
public class MeuReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent intentParaIniciarAtividade = new Intent(context, MinhaAtividade.class);
        intentParaIniciarAtividade.putBoolean(MinhaAtividade.EXTRA_LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA, true);
        context.startActivity(intentParaIniciarAtividade);
    }
}
```

**MinhaAtividade.java:**

```
public class MinhaAtividade extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA = MinhaAtividade.class.getPackage().getName() + ".LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_minha_atividade);

        if (true == getIntent().getBoolean(EXTRA_LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA, false)) {
            // Combinando duas flags: FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON e FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD.
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        }
    }
}
```

**Flags que podem ser combinadas nesse caso, dependendo da situação:**

Para destravar a tela:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD

Para exibir a Activity em frente à tela travada mas sem remover a trava:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Para ligar a iluminação da tela:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON

Para manter a tela ligada:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

**Observação importante:** Para as flags funcionarem, a janela que a `Activity` exibe deve ser uma janela que ocupa a tela inteira (*full screen*) e se encontrar no topo das outras activities.

(*Informações extraídas [dessa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623170/2241463)*).

Answer (score 0):

O intent que é disparado pelo android é [ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON).

Porém, você não pode registrar um intent filter no seu manifest para esse Intent. Você precisar registrado programaticamente usando o método registerReceiver().

Comment: O OP não quer saber quando a tela será ligada, ele quer ligar a tela ao receber um broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Só fazendo uma correção, para manter a tela ligada você utilizaria a *flag* [`FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON)

Comment: Amigos! o meu service executa o  `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` de tempo em tempo,  mas ele só liga a tela no primeiro ciclo. Existe solução para isso?